# GPA calculator in decimal format

Tags: java, decimalformat

I've got a program that's supposed to list out your gpa to the two nearest decimals places and I've got it down to the final line but I get an error message saying "non-static method format(double) cannot be referenced from a static context" here's my code

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GPACalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double creditHours = 0;
        double gradePoints = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter number of classes");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double numClass = scanner.nextInt();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        for(double i = 1; i <= numClass; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter credit hours for class "+ i);
            double aCreditHour = scanner.nextInt();
            creditHours += aCreditHour;
            System.out.println("Enter grade for class "+ i);
            String letter = scanner.next();
            if(letter.equals("A")){
                gradePoints = gradePoints + (4 * aCreditHour);
            } else if (letter.equals("B")){
                gradePoints = gradePoints + (3 * aCreditHour);
            } else if (letter.equals("C")){
                gradePoints = gradePoints + (2 * aCreditHour);
            } else if (letter.equals("D")){
                gradePoints = gradePoints + (1 * aCreditHour);
            } else if (letter.equals("F")){
                gradePoints = gradePoints + (0 * aCreditHour);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Your GPA is: " + DecimalFormat.format(gradePoints / creditHours));
    }
}
```

I know the problem is with the .format bit after the DecimalFormat, I just don't know how to fix it. I'm just kinda hoping to know what I'm supposed to replace it with

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the DecimalFormat first:

```
    DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat();
    System.out.println("Your GPA is: " + dFormat.format(gradePoints/creditHours));
```

You are directly calling a non-static method (DecimalFormat.format), which it's not possible! Only static methods can be called this way, the other way is to instantiate them and call it through instance.method()!